Maximum Likelihood Estimation with Gradient Descent and Squarred Loss
My goal is to learn parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ of a univariate Gaussian distribution using gradient descent to validate my understanding of the algorithm by deriving all the formulas from scratch. Moreover, I try to use the squared loss in place of log-likelihood to see whether the concept may work (even if less optimal than the log-likelihood itself). However, upon the empirical evaluation, the concept does not work, even giving a simple example. This suggests that I made some trivial mistake in my thinking about the GD in this case. Could you please validate/correct my understanding of the algorithm presented below?
Let $x_1 \in R$ be a feature and $y_1 \in R$ be a target.
We use a univariate Gaussian distribution $f(x, \mu, \sigma)$ to model a certain data distributing process. The goal is to learn parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$. Additionally, let $\eta > 0$ be a learning rate.

Initialize random $\mu$ and $\sigma$.
$\hat{y}$ = $(y - \hat{y})^2$
$\nabla_{\mu} = 2(y - \hat{y}) * \frac{(x - \mu)exp(- \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2})}{\sigma^2 \sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}$
$\nabla_{\sigma} = 2(y - \hat{y}) * (\frac{(x - \mu)^2exp(- \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2})}{\sigma^3 \sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} - \frac{\sigma exp(- \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}))}{\sigma^2 \sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}})$
$\mu = \mu - \eta * \nabla_{\mu}$
$\sigma = \sigma - \eta * \nabla_{\sigma}$

The process continues until convergence. This is not the most optimal way to learn parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ - and I am well aware of that - but it is a baseline derived by me that should work. Unless I make some trivial mistake that would suggest my lack of understanding of certain elements of the algorithm. Lines 3 and 4 are based on a chain rule - and I think that I made a mistake here. However, the partial derivates are correct, so the mistake must be in the application of the chain rule itself. Could I ask you for a verification of the algorithm? I am trying to solidify my understanding of SGD-based learning, and this mistake is not letting me go. Thank you very much for your help.
